# SSMS : Update Statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have the following code for updating a table

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempDraft (Seq int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,RqItmID bigint,GoodID int,UnitID int,Qty int,Price money,Amount money,Discount money,Added money,SysDis money,SysAdd money,isGift bit)
        INSERT INTO #TempDraft(GoodID,RqItmID,UnitID,Qty,Price,Amount,Discount,Added,SysDis,SysAdd,isGift)
        SELECT GoodID,R.RqItmID,Unit_ID,OrderQty,P_Price,(OrderQty * P_Price),Discount,Added,0,0,0 FROM @Comparison C JOIN SLE.vw_ReqItmFull R on R.RqItmID

            DECLARE @DisPer decimal(6,2),@DisAmnt money

            SET @DisPer = (SELECT TOP 1 DisPer FROM @F_Itm)
            SET @DisAmnt = (SELECT TOP 1 DisAmnt FROM @F_Itm)

                        DECLARE @LastDis money,@LastQty decimal(16,2),@LastAdd money,@LastPrice money,@LastAmount money

                        SET @LastDis = (SELECT TOP 1 SysDis FROM #TempDraft WHERE RqItmID = @ActiveRII)
                        SET @LastAdd = (SELECT TOP 1 SysAdd FROM #TempDraft WHERE RqItmID = @ActiveRII)
                        SET @LastPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM #TempDraft WHERE RqItmID = @ActiveRII)
                        SET @LastAmount = (SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM #TempDraft WHERE RqItmID = @ActiveRII)


                        IF @DisPer >= 0 begin
                             /* SECTION 1 */
                            /* THIS STATEMENT DOESNT WORK vv */
                            UPDATE #TempDraft
                            SET SysDis = @DisPer
                            WHERE RqItmID = @ActiveRII
                            /* THIS STATEMENT DOESNT WORK ^^ */
                        end

                        IF @DisAmnt >= 0 begin
                         /* SECTION 2 */
                            UPDATE #TempDraft 
                            SET SysDis = @LastDis + @DisAmnt
                            WHERE RqItmID = @ActiveRII

                        end
```

now the problem is SECTION 1 doesn't work. it does not update any part of any table. other parts of the code work correctly and if i remove the WHERE clause from the non working part, it works.

the SECTION 2 however is very similar to SECTION 1 and WHERE clause in both of them are the same but somehow SECTION 1 doesn't update and SECTION 2 works fine.

what should i do ???

thanks

Comment: I think you should try to add debugging statements, So you should try to print the values you are setting and check if the variables have values. what do you mean by not working? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: You have always either DisPer OR DisAmnt  which is greater then 0 ? Or may they be both greater then 0 ? In this case, Section2 could erase what have been done in section 1...

Comment: thanks @RaphaëlAlthaus !